# Is there an option to inspect live variable data like in Visual studio?

Tags: xcode

When I set break points in Visual Studio, I can inspect variables to see what they are set too: int's, string's, array's, etc..

Is there an option similar in XCode to help with debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - open Xcode's help and search for **Debugging with Xcode** - there are links to WWDC videos, and ample documentation to get you going.